# How to add a rectangle to PathFigure WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles, pathgeometry

I was totally tired of adding a `Rectangle` to a path figure. Below was my tried code, but it does not results correctly as a `Rectangle`:

```
PathGeometry geom = new PathGeometry();
Geometry g = new RectangleGeometry(myrectangel);
geom.AddGeometry(g);

PathFigureCollection collection = geom.Figures;
pathfigure = collection[0];
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combined geometries using a [GeometryGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup.aspx). A `GeometryGroup` creates a composite geometry from one or more `Geometry` objects.

```
GeometryGroup gg = new GeometryGroup();            
gg.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)));
gg.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)));
gg.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(200, 200, 100, 100)));

System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
path.Data = gg;
path.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
```

Comment: Thanks Nitesh... but i need to add it to PathFigure and use it at last as i have many rectagles like the above....///

Comment: You can use `GeometryGroup`.